# Is position_embeddings function removed from BertModel?

Tags: bert-language-model

While running the code with Bert and transformer, I get this error :

`got an unexpected keyword argument 'position_embeddings'`

Part code where error comes is this -

```
from transformers import  BertModel

self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
text_embed = self.bert.embeddings.position_embeddings(text_positions)
```

text_positions is the input

Can someone suggest what is missing. Have installed transformer using pip install transformers

Comment: `bert.embeddings.position_embeddings` works for me, I don't see any error in the code provided by you.

Comment: most likely, you might have make some other mistake in the original code.

Comment: Also when running below code                                                                                              
                                                                                                                             ```
from transformers import BertConfig, BertModel, BertOnlyMLMHead
```
getting this error

ImportError: cannot import name 'BertOnlyMLMHead' from 'transformers' (unknown location)

Searched and got this discussion - https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/186

can BertForMaskedLM be used instead of BertOnlyMLMHead

Comment: Seems like the class `BertOnlyMLMHead` was from a older version. Take a look at `BertForMaskedLM`, it might be relevant.

Comment: are there standard available ways to create position_ids (passed as parameter to forward method of BertModel)

Comment: position embeddings depends on the position of the tokens, they are sequential.